# How to integrate link in a react component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to put the social media link in one of my react project. Unfortunately, the code is not working. May I please ask what type of mistake am I doing?

```
import {L10n} from "@pythonbuddha/l10n";
...
...
<span className="social-media-icon">
              <YouTube className="youtube_logo"
                href={onClick}
                href={L10n.format("youtube-link")}
                target="_blank"
              />
              </span>
```

**l10 is the JSON file***

```
"youtube-link":"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQM-UwJfNuDzD-6GUCRcXog",

"facebook-link":"https://de-de.facebook.com/LenzeDeutschland",
```

Comment: What is in the `<YouTube />` component? And there is no content in the `<a>` element so the link may be there just invisible.

Comment: What is `L10n.format` part? A library?

Comment: ```<YouTube />``` is Google Material Design Icon.

Comment: L10.format contains variable called ```youtube-link```, where I store the link of the youtube.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something but if youtube-link is a variable it shouldn’t have quotes. Not sure if that what is “not working” but seems funny. Maybe that’s a variable inside the format function?

I may be missing something but if youtube-link is a variable it shouldn’t have quotes. Not sure if that what is “not working” but seems funny. Maybe that’s a variable inside the format function?

Maybe try surrounding the icon with an anchor tag and removing onClick:

```
<a href={L10n.format("youtube-link")} target="_blank">
     <YouTube className="youtube_logo" />
</a
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it is still not working. For more details, I included l10 file which contains variables to save the web link. May I ask please if you can have a look again on my question?

Comment: See edits, missing some detail in your question but that's my best shot